# JQuery Upload File from Dialog window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload, upload, dialog

I try to upload file from Dialog (JQuery UI) window like:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [{ text: "Upload", click: function() 
{ $(     ".selector" ). append('<form action="../test/test_upload.php" 
method="POST" name="getnamefile">
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile">
<input type="submit" id="Submit" name= "Submit" value="Upload"></form>'); }....
```

and on php parth:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

$upfl = $_POST['uploadfile'];
$target_path = "../tmp/"; 

//if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'])) 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
 echo "There was an error uploading the file";
}
```

Always receive error "There was an error uploading the file"
If use 2 file html and the same php - all work ok.
What be the reason? It seems that all identical.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form.